# Cannot find localhost file

Tags: localhost

Someone created a index.htm file on my pc before but I couldn't find the htm doc anymore(forgot where it was located).

Now I need to display something through my localhost on my browser but it just keeps displaying the old page whenever I type "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 on the address bar.

Is there any way I can reset the localhost page back to default?

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????????????????? The number of question marks is basically the long form of WTF.

Comment: I **THINK** what the OP is asking is "How do I find where the web server installed on my machine has its root folder so I can change the index.html file to something else?" but this is so far off topic: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onpen `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager` on  `Administrative tools`,

Find `Default Web` Site on left tree, then right click on it and choose explore, you will find htm in there. if you remove index.htm, localhost will show you the default page.

Comment: Wow, how did you guess that he is on Windows and that he uses IIS? What if he uses Linux? And Apache?

Comment: You will help him/her if my guess wrong.

Comment: Or more likely, point the user in the direction of another stack exchange site. [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) seems more appropriate to me.